# Is there a Reverse Image search for images on a hard drive?

Tags: search

I have a large number of images on my computer that I downloaded with name and attribution included in the filename, but which have been renamed to gibberish alphanumeric titles in a transference glitch. I would like to look them up online to find the original information. Is there a tool that would allow me to do an online similarity search without having to upload them to the web?

I can use pretty much anything that works under Windows or Linux (with GUI, I don't see command-line being appropriate for this).

Comment: They would have to be uploaded at some point as you need to make them available to google's or tineye's engine (so that the engine can compare to the database). If the API supports it, it might just be possible to hash the image locally, but I think that's unlikely (the hash method is probably proprietary). Google's APIs are quite scriptable, so you may be able to do something there. Don't forget you don't need the full resolution for a search - you could pass through ImageMagick to rescale to something like 25% before uploading.

Comment: Are your originals stored on a particular service, or are they just Out There Somewhere?

Comment: @Olivier it's not even an answer to the Q if you consider "probably not" to be an answer. It's a note about what features would be needed and some hints in case the OP wants to make their own tool.

Comment: @Olivier if I knew enough I would! But while I'd find writing a python script to do it an interesting puzzle, I haven't got that kind of time.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer this question, but it might be a useful read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api

Comment: @mattdm They're on my computer at the moment. I know they exist Out There Somewhere on the net, as that's where I got them, and that's where the correct metadata exists.

Comment: This is a software request for an image searching tool. It is not about taking or editing photographs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a tool that would allow me to do **an online similarity search** without having to upload them to the web?

At this time, **there is no tool** to allow anyone to do an **online search** without uploading data to the servers.